# Snapshot of balances of all token holders at a particular block

Tags: tokens, snapshot

Is there any way to get a snapshot of balances of all the token holders or the holders list at particular block. Looking for some API or tool other than web3 way to iterate over all the `Transfer` events emitted by the token contract.

Answer (score 0):

Try [holders.at](https://holders.at) tool that lets you do exactly this — export token holders at any block.

For example, here's a page to all token holders for `0x5a98fcbea516cf06857215779fd812ca3bef1b32` token at a block height `15000000:` https://holders.at/ethereum/0x5a98fcbea516cf06857215779fd812ca3bef1b32/15000000

Answer (score 0):

Radiant is exactly doing that, the tool: https://segment.radiant.so/ and the API docs: https://docs.radiant.so